# JSRender: does not work after a certain amount of lines of code?

Tags: jsrender

I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u1ntrex8/5/)  of my problem. For some reason once the program comes to line 123 in HTML section it does not load. Below is the section of code that apparently does not work, eventhough I have tried it out earlier in the HTML section, meaning at the beginning of the document.

```
<h5>{{>DescriptionTitle}}</h5>
<br/>
<ul class="topit-items">
  {{for Description}}
    <li>{{>}}</li>
  {{/for}}
</ul>
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have concluded that it must be some aspect of JSRender, that is hindering me to load the full code.

My questions are why is this happening? And what is the  best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your demo has invalid HTML, with no closing script tag on the template declaration.

After fixing that, the issue is this line

```
<!-- <f:link.external ... uri="...advertNumber={{>AdvertNumber}"> -->
```

which should be:

```
<!-- <f:link.external ... uri="...advertNumber={{>AdvertNumber}}"> -->
```

Note that comment tags still get rendered by JsRender, so need to have valid markup. OTOH you can use JsRender comment tags to exclude from the output as in:

```
{{!-- <f:link.external ... uri="...advertNumber={{>AdvertNumber}}"> --}}
```

Within the JsRender comment tag the erroneous `{{>AdvertNumber}` would have been OK...

See https://jsfiddle.net/u1ntrex8/6/